# Confusing between webapp using NodeJs server and electron

Tags: node.js, ember.js, electron

I am learning how to develop a desktop app with Electron. I developed websites long time ago in php with session variables and many `include`.

I want a navbar with some pages. When we click on a link in the navbar, only the page below will change, I want to avoid the white flash.

I read **a lot** but I am still confused since there is no server in Electron to check everything.

For example how to make a login webpage with a simple password ?!

In PHP I would send the form to a PHP page using POST that will process the password server-side and then display or not the content and create a flag session variable in order to allow or not other pages.

But since everybody could see the javascript code and then the fixed  in-code password, it is still confusing.

**Possible solution:**
Using Ember or AngularJs for the routing only but I still didn't find the way to include a page which the content will be conditionally displayed. In PHP just insert the html in `if` statement.

**My project:**
I have a socket server which send me in real-time data, I want to connect to the server and display the data only if the user is allowed. The server and the data are depending on the page.

- Should I consider the main process as a NodeJs server and the render process the client side ?

Please if my question doesn't follow the rules, just tell me in comment, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not ready to develop desktop app with ember and electron, if you have no experience with Ember.js or at least theoretical knowledge of Ember.js. You should start from reading [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/) to understand how to create SPA using this framework.

After that you will be able to use [ember-electron](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-electron) to create desktop apps.

About authentication: if you have a server, it should decide when to give a data, not client. On client side you can use [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) to store tokens and authorize requests, and on server side you setup auth server (depending on used on backend technology, ready to use 3rd-party libraries may exist).

Comment: I'd say it's unfair to accuse him of incapability. I'm from a basic web stack background and ASP.NET, but that doesn't stop me from practicing Node.js and Electron. Things take practice.

Comment: @Crowes ember (and I believe angular as well) is a complex front-end framework. And it can be very confusing in the beginning. In my opinion, adding to all that confusion electron is just wrong. That's why I say he is not ready and should start from ember basics and after then move to electron.

Comment: You're right, I need to learn first with a simple web server and then trying to make the app with electron. Just my socket is using node-ipc to send only binary data while nodeJs webserver send Json files.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev He noted Ember as a routing solution, when he could just use Express for whatever he wanted routed. As for Electron, he really only needs to know a bit of JS, which isn't difficult coming from PHP.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP you can: 1) Create static website in plain html+js. But html by itself doesn't have such thing, as include in php. If you want, you can use gulp for more comfortable developing (it can build html files from templates, if configured right). 2) Start a local web-server using node and create some dynamic website with that. It would require some knowledge of node.js. 3) Learn to pilot fighter aircraft and create a good SPA. In my opinion it's the best choice, but I don't know what you need. Are you sure you need electron? Maybe just a dynamic website?

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP couple of words about electron/node-webkit. Basically, app built with electron is just a web-application that runs in its own browser. What makes it special is: 1) access to node.js api (which allows access to file system and other cool things). 2) Ability to control browser's behavior (you can make cross-domain requests, control browser's window, intercept navigation). 3) Ability to work without internet connection (if your app is useful without server). Also size of such app is big. If you don't need these features, you don't need electron, you need a website.

Comment: Actually, you're right, I used atom, gitkraken and I found it very good but for now I gave up the idea to use electron. I need to learn again how to design a website. I am trying to use ExpressJs with EJS as a template manager. When everything is clear, I'll try to use Angular or Ember, maybe I even dont need them. Thank you for your messages !

Answer (score 1):

About client : I built a [seed](https://github.com/Kazuia/electron-forge-angular) working with AngularJS and more especifically with the awesome electron-forge. Maybe it can help you to understand how Angular could be combined for your projects. It answers to all your needs I guess.

But I'm joining the other answer : take time to learn how Angular or Ember (or one of many client-sided frameworks) works before anything.

You can start to learn with an [interactive course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) or just get knowledges in different web courses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this !